# Windows has triggered a breakpoint in my Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, visual-c++

In my application I'm loading (for example) Device_Manager.dll and this `Device_Manager` depend on the selected model start to load the correct Devices.dll.

In my Device_Manager.dll, I created a window to use its `handle` later on my `Devices` because `Devices` uses this `handle` when they want to send messages to the application.

So, I made the new `thread` in my `Device_Manager.dll` to get these message when ever they arrive!

(I'm also using QT for create/load .dlls.)

After I created a thread, I received this error:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in sepanta.agent.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in sepanta.agent.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while sepanta.agent.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

I use these two methods to initialize and start my device manager:

(These methods are called in the main application after I successfully load the .dll.)

```
bool DeviceManagerPlugin::initializeDeviceManager()
{
    EventManager pEventManager = new EventManager();
    bool init_result = pEventManager->initilize_window();

        ...

    if(initilize_status == S_OK)
    {   
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void DeviceManagerPlugin::startDeviceManager()
{
    
    handle_of_thread = 0;
    int data_of_thread = 1;
    
    handle_of_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0,listenToIncomingWFSMessages2, &data_of_thread, 0, NULL);  

    my_thread_handle = handle_of_thread;

}
```

This is my `EventManager` class, which created windows:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
     ...
     
     default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
    }
}

bool EventManager::initialize_window()
{
    WNDCLASS Wclass;
    HWND gHwnd = NULL;
    HINSTANCE gHinstance = NULL;

    ZeroMemory(&Wclass, sizeof(WNDCLASS));

    Wclass.hInstance = gHinstance;
    Wclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    Wclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    Wclass.lpszClassName = TEXT("Device_Manager_Class_Name");
    Wclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    Wclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    Wclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    Wclass.hCursor = LoadIcon(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    Wclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    Wclass.style = CS_OWNDC;


    if(!RegisterClass(&Wclass))
    {
        cout<<"Unable to Register Class";

        return false;
    }

    ULONG Window_Width;
    ULONG Window_Height;
    DWORD style;

    bool full_screen = false;

    if(full_screen)
    {
        Window_Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        Window_Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
        style = WS_POPUP;
    }
    else
    {
        Window_Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
        Window_Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
        style = WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_SYSMENU;
    }

    gHwnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("Device_Manager_Class_Name")
        , TEXT("Device_Manager_Class_Title")                 
        , style              
        , 0
        , 0
        , Window_Width
        , Window_Height
        , GetDesktopWindow()
        , NULL
        , gHinstance
        , NULL);

    if(!gHwnd)
    {
        cout<<"Unable to create the main window";

        return false;
    }

    //ShowWindow(gHwnd, SW_SHOW);
    //UpdateWindow(gHwnd);
    //SetFocus(gHwnd);

    return true;
}

 DWORD WINAPI listenToIncomingWFSMessages2(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    MSG msg;
    SecureZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));

    BOOL bRet; 

    HWND windows_handle;
    SecureZeroMemory(&windows_handle, sizeof(HWND));
   
    windows_handle = FindWindow(TEXT("Device_Manager_Class_Name"), 0);
    
    while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, windows_handle, 0, 0 )) != 0)
    { 
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            // handle the error and possibly exit
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        }
    } 
    
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  What did I miss? If you have a better solution for what I'm about to do, please feel free to share it with me.

Comment: Did you run the app in a debugger and reproduce the error there? Then you'll get the call stack and other useful stuff. Also using MS AppVerifier is a good idea to detect wrong usage of MS APIs.

Comment: So the problem is you're running it *not* in the debugger but it's tripping and prompting if you want to debug it?  prompted debugs usually occur with "debug" .exe/.dll's when they encounter some problem...

Comment: `EventManager pEventManager = new EventManager();` this is already fishy, it shows that either your code is not what you display here or that you don't have copying and assignment of your types in control. That said, this looks like Java/C#, which is the wrong language to use when programming in C++. Lastly, check the documentation of CreateThread(). In short, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt, I dont understand what you meaning, EventManager * pEventManager = new EventManager(); is creating instance so i can create my windows and ...

Comment: Look at your code, there is no asterisk! This means that the above code is too far from the real code to be helpful. Further, in C++, you create an instance with "EventManager em;", i.e. no "new" involved like in Java or C#. If you use "new", there should be a good reason for it and you should be aware of all the implications.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich Eckhardt, I changed my structure and didn't use new and it work how ever i got another problem trying to fix, Thanks again